# Is this XSD regex makes sense and/or POSIX compliant?

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I stumbled upon type defintion in XSD like:

```
<xs:pattern value="[0-9]{9}|">
```

that does not make too much sense to me.

First, trying to validate an `.xml` file against this regex by `xmllint` I am getting an error:

```
regexp error: failed to compile: expecting a branch after |
.... the value '[0-9]{9}|' is not a valid regular expression
```

Second, not surprisingly, when running `grep -E` with this `regex` in Linux terminal it matches `ANY` string.

So I'am having two questions with this regex:

1. Does it make sense at all as it matches anything?
2. Is this `regex` `POSIX` compliant? (concerning `the value '[0-9]{9}' is not a valid regular expression)`

**UPDATE**

Is there a way to make an XSD regex that matches exactly '[0-9]{9}' or an empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex in `<xs:pattern value="[0-9]{9}|">` is a valid regex in itself, since what it matches is

- `[0-9]{9}` - 9 digits
- `|` - or
- an empty string.

Thus, the pattern matches an empty string, or - if unanchored - would find a match in any string, even in [`$%%^%^`](https://regex101.com/r/pMJ4tk/1).

However, missing text in a regex branch is considered as a human error by some engines. It is not surprising, as people often make typos like `\d||\s`.

If you use the pattern with `sed`, you will see [it is working well](https://ideone.com/F6YGF3), so it is POSIX compliant. However, in XSD schema (that is not POSIX, but a separate regex flavor), you should avoid empty branches, and just use an optional group:

```
<xs:pattern value="([0-9]{9})?">
```

Comment: Thanks, for answering `POSIX` part of the question! Could you please name the XSD's regex flavor?

Comment: XSD Schema regex is a separate type of regex flavor, it is very specific. It has some similarities with .NET (e.g. it supports character class subtraction) but it is wierd that there is no word boundary and `^`/`$`  anchor support (the pattern is anchored to start/end of string input by default). See [more about XSD Schema regex here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html).

Comment: @Sergey, The XSD regex flavor is defined in the [second part](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs) of XSD specs, which defines its data types. Note that it changed over time, so it even differs between XSD versions (in subtle ways). It is simply referred to as `XML schema regular expression`.

Comment: Wiktor, concerning your suggested `<xs:pattern value="([0-9]{9})?">`. I suppose the intent of the XSD's author was to match the pattern if string is either empty or the regex before the pipe. However, both `echo abc | grep -E "[0-9]{9}|"` and `echo abc | grep -E "([0-9]{9})?"` produce `abc`. Is there a way to address question I asked in the **UPDATE** ?

Comment: You forgot to anchor the pattern used with *grep*. As mentioned in my answer, XSD Schema regex requires a full string match. So, if you want the same functionality with grep you must use anchors, `grep -E '^([0-9]{9}|)$'`. Or `'^([0-9]{9})?$'`.

Answer (score 2):

`[0-9]{9}|` is a valid regular expression in XSD 1.0 and XSD 1.1, it means the same as `([0-9]{9})?`, that is, it matches a sequence of nine digits or nothing.

The question of whether it is POSIX compliant is quite irrelevant since the XSD specification makes no reference to POSIX.

The question as to whether it makes sense can I think be answered "yes". It's unusual to see "|" with an empty branch, it's much more common to express this requirement using the "?" operator, but its meaning is perfectly well-defined.

Comment: What you wrote is absolutely right! My problem was that XSD was parsed by Python based instrument, namely PyXB, that did not parse that regex "quite" as expected. Then I learnt about XML regex flavor and solved the problem by re-writing the regex. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 1):

`[0-9]{9}|` means 9 digits **or empty string** if your parser is lax enough. If not, it's looking for an alternation after the pipe. You should remove the pipe